# In nginx open route of app as index

Tags: angular, nginx

I have a server executing Nginx and serving one Angular 4 application. That site is served under `www.mysite.com`
Now, I have another domain, called `www.mySecondDomain.com` but this site should open one route of the same angular app, I means:

- mysite.com will open the index route of the application: /
- mySecondDomain.com will open one route of the application: /theRoute

What should I configure in Nginx in order to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: I would not do any change on nginx in this case, you have to set up an A-record or CNAME where you bought your domain

Answer (score 0):

You can Use [Reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) to achieve such thing , try [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) and start your Angular app as a localhost in your server and assign that localhost address in your [Reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) to show your first domain and assign localhost/theRoute to show your second domain.this will be Angular side of your problem .

but for more info on Nginx configuration  : https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to configure nginx. Just add a WWW-redirect rule where you bought your domain, or with your (D)NS-provider. Set `mySecondDomain.com` to be redirected to `mysite.com/theRoute`

Comment: @Jhon that is not what I want. The redirects will give me status 301, I need to see in the URL mySecondDomain.com still and get status code 200